# In TCPView, what does the * mean in the Remote Address field

Tags: windows, networking, tcp

In [TCPView](http://www.google.co.uk/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=tcpview&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CFoQFjAA&url=http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx&ei=gVTHT7PXCefU0QX7xc27Dw&usg=AFQjCNHRgjKA1pt-MzSBvfqM0fg7xWl5yg&cad=rja) what does the * mean in the remote address field.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Those are for listening sockets, i.e. sockets open on your machine waiting to receive incoming  connections.

If you see a `*` there, it means the socket is ready for connections from anywhere. If you see a hostname or IP address, then only connections from those are accepted.